# Excel to Calculate Selling Price based on First in First Out

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

i have multiple MaterialNo's and i am giving example of only one Material No now. There is Type Column that tells whether we have Bought or Sold the Material on a particular date. i have already Sorted data based on Material No and Date. Now i want to implement **FIFO logic** to calculate Total Price and Unit Price for Sold Materials. I have Manually Calculated as of now in Excel .

```
MaterialNo  Type    Date    Qty   Price   Balance-Quantity **TotalPrice**   **UnitPrice**
XXXXXX     Buy      03-2017 1250    79.99998042 1250    99999.97552     79.99998042
XXXXXX     Sell     03-2017   20                1230    -1599.999608    -79.99998042
XXXXXX     Buy      04-2017 2200    79.99999667 3430    175999.9927      79.99999667
XXXXXX     Sell     04-2017 2375                1055    -189999.9721    -79.99998825
XXXXXX     Buy      05-2017  997    79.9999625  2052    79759.96261      79.9999625
XXXXXX     Sell     05-2017 2055                  -3    -164399.9229    -79.9999625
XXXXXX     Buy      06-2017 4749    79.99996153 4746    379919.8173      79.99996153
XXXXXX     Sell     06-2017 3550                1196    -283999.8669    -79.9999625
XXXXXX     Buy      07-2017  894    80.00001111 2090    71520.00993      80.00001111
XXXXXX     Sell     07-2017 2100                 -10    -167999.9213    -79.9999625
XXXXXX     Buy      08-2017 2495    137.210024  2485    342339.0098      137.210024
XXXXXX     Sell     08-2017 1900                 585    -260699.0455    -137.210024
XXXXXX     Buy      09-2017 2000    156.28      2585    312560           156.28
XXXXXX     Sell     09-2017 2652                 -67    -414454.56      -156.28
XXXXXX     Buy      10-2017  596    156.2805875  529    93143.23015      156.2805875
XXXXXX     Sell     10-2017  476                  53    -74389.55965    -156.2805875
XXXXXX     Buy      11-2017 5600    156.2800066 5653    875168.0371      156.2800066
XXXXXX     Sell     11-2017 1111                4542    -173627.0874    -156.2800066
XXXXXX     Buy      12-2017 1118    156.2800863 5660    174721.1365      156.2800863
XXXXXX     Sell     12-2017 1222                4438    -190974.2654    -156.2800863
XXXXXX     Buy      01-2018 2162    156.28      6600    337877.36        156.28
XXXXXX     Sell     01-2018 4188                2412    -654500.64      -156.28
XXXXXX     Buy      02-2018  792    156.2796819 3204    123773.5081      156.2796819
XXXXXX     Sell     02-2018 2602                 602    -406639.7323    -156.2796819
XXXXXX     Buy      03-2018  400    156.28      1002    62512            156.28
XXXXXX     Sell     03-2018  560                 442    -87516.8        -156.28
```

**Another Scenario where there is no negative balance quantity**

```
MaterialNo  Type    Date    Qty Price   Balance Quantity    TotalPrice  Unit Price
SSSSSSSS    Buy 06-2017 30  140.8   30  4224    140.8
SSSSSSSS    Sell    06-2017 30      0   -4224   -140.8
SSSSSSSS    Buy 07-2017 150 140.8   150 21120   140.8
SSSSSSSS    Sell    07-2017 16      134 -2252.8 -140.8
SSSSSSSS    Sell    08-2017 22      112 -3097.6 -140.8
SSSSSSSS    Buy 09-2017 150 207.4399333 262 31115.99    207.4399333
SSSSSSSS    Sell    09-2017 112     150 -15769.6    -140.8
SSSSSSSS    Buy 10-2017 250 207.4399    400 51859.975   207.4399
SSSSSSSS    Sell    10-2017 63      337 -13068.7158 -207.4399333
SSSSSSSS    Buy 11-2017 3260    207.4399991 3597    676254.3969 207.4399991
SSSSSSSS    Sell    11-2017 2655        942 -550753.167 -207.4399876
SSSSSSSS    Buy 12-2017 300 207.44  1242    62232   207.44
SSSSSSSS    Sell    12-2017 556     686 -115336.6395    -207.4399991
SSSSSSSS    Buy 01-2018 428 207.44002   1114    88784.32856 207.44002
SSSSSSSS    Sell    01-2018 448     666 -92933.11964    -207.4399992
SSSSSSSS    Buy 02-2018 -9  207.44  657 -1866.96    207.44
SSSSSSSS    Sell    02-2018 332     325 -68870.08188    -207.4400057
SSSSSSSS    Buy 03-2018 699 207.43997   1024    145000.539  207.43997
SSSSSSSS    Sell    03-2018 341     683 -70737.0462 -207.4400182
```

One thing to note - When ever Balance Quantity is negative, it should calculate Total Price for Sold material based on last bought price. Let me know for any questions.

This is the function i tried.

```
Dim prc As Double
Function fifoval(q As Range, Optional details As String) As Variant
Application.Volatile (True)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim qstr As String
    Dim pstr As String
    Dim cqty As Integer
    Dim qty As Integer
    Dim ctr As Integer
    Dim dstr As String
    Dim amt As Double
    'Stop
    For i = 2 To q.Row - 1
        If Cells(i, 1) = Cells(q.Row, 1) And IsNumeric(Cells(i, 7)) Then
            Select Case Cells(i, 2)
                Case "Buy"
                    qstr = qstr & Cells(i, 4) & ","
                    pstr = pstr & Cells(i, 5) & ","
                Case "Sell"
                    qty = Cells(i, 4)
                    Do While qty > 0

                        cqty = Val(qstr)
                        If (cqty = 0) Then
                            fifoval = "Not enough balance"
                            Exit Function
                        End If
                        Select Case True
                            Case cqty = qty
                                qstr = Replace(qstr, cqty & ",", "", , 1)
                                pstr = Replace(pstr, Val(pstr) & ",", "", , 1)
                                qty = qty - cqty
                            Case cqty > qty
                                qstr = Replace(qstr, cqty, cqty - qty, , 1)
                                qty = 0
                            Case cqty < qty
                                qstr = Replace(qstr, cqty & ",", "", , 1)
                                pstr = Replace(pstr, Val(pstr) & ",", "", , 1)
                                qty = qty - cqty
                            Case cqty = 0
                                fifoval = "Not enough balance"
                                Exit Function
                        End Select
                        ctr = ctr + 1
                        If ctr > 1000 Then End: Stop
                    Loop
            End Select
        End If
    Next i
    qty = Cells(q.Row, 4)
    Do While qty > 0

        cqty = Val(qstr)
        If (cqty = 0) Then
            fifoval = "Not enough balance"
            Exit Function
        End If
        prc = Val(pstr)
        Select Case True
            Case cqty = qty
                dstr = dstr & IIf(dstr = "", "", " + ") & qty & " * " & prc
                amt = amt + qty * prc
                qstr = Replace(qstr, cqty & ",", "", , 1)
                pstr = Replace(pstr, Val(pstr) & ",", "", , 1)
                qty = qty - cqty
            Case cqty > qty
                dstr = dstr & IIf(dstr = "", "", " + ") & qty & " * " & prc
                amt = amt + qty * prc
                qstr = Replace(qstr, cqty, cqty - qty, , 1)
                qty = 0
            Case cqty < qty
                dstr = dstr & IIf(dstr = "", "", " + ") & cqty & " * " & prc
                amt = amt + cqty * prc
                qstr = Replace(qstr, cqty & ",", "", , 1)
                pstr = Replace(pstr, Val(pstr) & ",", "", , 1)
                qty = qty - cqty
        End Select
        ctr = ctr + 1
        If ctr > 1000 Then End: Stop
    Loop
    If details = "" Then
        fifoval = amt
    Else
        fifoval = dstr
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: What's your question?  Is the function throwing any run-time errors.  It compiles OK.

Comment: it compiles ok but with wrong results.... if you compare Total Price and Unit Price given in this post with compiled results, it  does not match

Comment: It looks like your buy price is correct. Your sell price is however always the same as the previous buy price.

Comment: @Luuklag that is the case here... another scenario will be where you wont have negative balance quantity. in that case calculation differs.

Comment: i have updated another scenario in the question. pls check

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't understand the exact problem. The tables you posted are calculated manually?

Comment: yes....manually calculated using FIFO logic.

Comment: i dont see any body able to resolve this? i guess its quite tricky

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do the same thing and without VBA and I came up with a solution that needs to create some extra columns.

On my example the columns are as follows for row 367.

Data:

- Column D: Date.
- Column E: Product Name.
- Column I: Quantity. If it's a sell the quantity is negative so you would need to create a new column if you want to use this formula that provides the quantity in negative if it's a sale.
- Column J: Price.
- Column N: Exchange Rate (I guess you don't need that).

Formulas:

- Column AA: Amount of current product on the row and in the date of the operation:

  `=+IF(I367="","",MAX(0,MIN(I367,SUMIF(E:E,E367,I:I)- 
  SUMIFS(I:I,D:D,">"&D367,E:E,E367,I:I,">0"))))`
- Column AB: Cost price of the amount of current product on the row and in the date of the operation:

  `=IF(AA367="","",ROUND(AA367*N367*J367,2))`
- Column AC: Cost price of the amount of product already sold on the date of the operation:

  `=IF(I367="","",IF(I367>0,ROUND((I367-AA367)*N367*J367,2),0))`
- Column AD: Sale price of the amount of product already sold on the date of the operation: 
  `=+IF(I367<0,ROUND(-I367*J367*N367,2),"")`

Once you have those columns you only need to do totals by column:

- Total Column AB: Cost of all the material you have stored.
- Total Column AC: All the money spent buying the material you already sold.
- Total Column AD: Income for all the product you have sold.

You'd need to reformulate the formulas to match your columns but other than that it should work.